# jQuery json parse: Get incorrect value in field 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've trying to parse an JSON-Request from the server which look like this:

```
{"data": [[1399621731000, 11], [1399555314000, 5], [1399461551000, 1]]}
```

When i get the data from the server with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someURL,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.data);
    }
});
```

Sometimes i get an empty value at position 1:

```
0: Array[2]
1: 0
2: Array[2]
```

If I refresh the page a several time in only a few request i get the right value. The server request is always the same. It is really confusing.

I tried it with several jQuery an the $.getJSON function but nothing works.
Currently i use jQuery  1.10 and test it with Google Chrome.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's only the second value, the issue is probably serverside, as parsing JSON doesn't really just spit out random errors like that.

Comment: Hmm. I opened the requested url in the browser an refreshed it a several times. It is always the same response.

No the server send it correct. Its just a typo. I validate it with an online validator

Comment: Problem in server response. Check once your server json object.

Comment: debug with alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

Comment: I checked the response in the server and i checked the request in the Chrome Web Inspector. The Web Inspector parse it correctly.

Comment: The output of the debug is correct but if i try to use this value it is 0 :(